# Reading config file present in the test script directory

Tags: python, nosetests

I have some test scripts written and a config file in one directory say /home/xyz.
I am executing nosetest command `nosetests -v -s /home/xyz`.

In the test script I am reading  the config file which is place in xyz directory.
As I am executing the nosetest command from the parent directory it is not getting the config file.

I wanted to know if there is anyway that nosetest will search for config file in the directory from where it is getting the tests to run.

Comment: Where is your piece of code that is doing this for you ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal Sorry did not get that

Comment: I meant to sat that, Have a written any code for doing the same ? If yes then kindly paste it up here

Comment: All I wanted to know is , is there any way that to know the direcroty from which the tests are been picked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting configuration in your project’s `/home/xyz/setup.cfg` file? `.noserc` or `nose.cfg` are for your home directory only, as [explained in the extended usage](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

You can also specify config file explicitly with `nosetests -c=FILE` as described [here](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#cmdoption-c):

> -c=FILES, --config=FILES
>   Load configuration from config file(s). May be specified multiple times; in that case, all config files will be loaded and combined

Comment: sure . Even I came across this will check